# Cronjob on App Engine results in a Method Not Allowed error (405)

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-endpoints

I am attempting to run a [cronjob](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) on App Engine with Endpoints.

I am receiving a Method Not Allowed (HTTP 405) error when I use the cronjob. How can I get around this error?

Here is my current `cron.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/_ah/spi/messaging/v1/checkUpdates</url>
        <description>Check for news every 5 minutes</description>
        <schedule>every 5 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
    <cron>
        <url>/_ah/spi/package.backend.MessagingEndpoint.checkUpdates</url>
        <description>Check for news every 5 minutes</description>
        <schedule>every 5 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

My Endpoint without code body:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "checkUpdatesPost",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST
)
public void checkUpdatesPost() {
    checkUpdates();
}

@ApiMethod(
        name = "checkUpdates",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET
)
public void checkUpdates() {
    // ... Stuff
}
```

Running either of these functions through [Google APIs Explorer](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/) runs correctly:

Testing with `GET`

```
GET https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/messaging/v1/checkUpdates
```

Testing with `POST`

```
POST https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/messaging/v1/checkUpdatesPost
```

Here is the log, as seen on the [Logs Viewer](https://console.developers.google.com/):

[image]

You can see here `AppEngine-.` refers to an attempt by Cron. `Chrome 48` is an attempt by my browser / Google APIs Explorer.

As I understand it, Cron *does not* work with `POST`. For this reason, I created another function for `GET` that mirrors the function of `POST`.

In my `cron.xml` I supplied two variations.

1. `/_ah/spi/messaging/v1/checkUpdates` - This is what I would use in a browser to access the resource.
2. `/_ah/spi/package.backend.MessagingEndpoint.checkUpdates` - This is what I see in the Logs Viewer once I have run #1 in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be clearly stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_calling_google_cloud_endpoints).

> Calling Google Cloud Endpoints
>
> You cannot call a Google Cloud Endpoint from a cron job. Instead, you
>   should issue a request to a target that is served by a handler that's
>   specified in your app's configuration file or in a dispatch file. That
>   handler then calls the appropriate endpoint class and method.